# No such file or directory error for <private/*.h> includings when build in Qt

Tags: qt, build, include, qmake

I'm newbie and never build from source files before, and tried to build QtCharts.

I downloaded source for QtCharts 5.12, and it has prepared .pro file. So I launched this .pro file in Qt Creator, did qmake first, then launched build.
It displays a billion errors for <private/*.h> includings. For example:

```
D:\QtProjects\qtcharts-5.12.0\src\charts\linechart\qlineseries.cpp:31: error: private/qlineseries_p.h: No such file or directory
 #include <private/qlineseries_p.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How to deal with these errors and why is this "private" prefix needed?